# Passing cyrillic character into stored procedure doesn't work Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure

```
if OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.spGetProducts') is not null
drop procedure dbo.spGetProducts
go

CREATE procedure [dbo].[spGetProducts]
(
 @sort_col varchar(100), @sort_dir varchar(4),
 @start int, @num int, @filters nvarchar(2000)) as
 begin
 declare @end int
 declare    
  @res table 
  (
   row_num int,
   product_name nvarchar(max)
  )
set @end = @start+@num
insert into @res
EXEC
(
 'select * from 
  (
   select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY '+@sort_col+' '+@sort_dir+')) row_num,
   * FROM (select product_name from Products where '+@filters+') as x
  ) as tmp where row_num between '+@start+' and '+@end
) select row_num, product_name from @res
 end 
go
```

When I execute the stored procedure with `latin characters` works perfectly, but when I use `cyrillic` characters `does not return anything`..

This is the execute line:

1. Latin characters - working:

   ```
   exec dbo.spGetProducts 'product_name','desc',0,50,' 
   product_name like N''%abs%'''
   ```
2. Cyrillic characters - not worikng:

   ```
   exec dbo.spGetProducts 'product_name','desc',0,50,' 
   product_name like N''%абв%'''
   ```

Also I manually set the stored procedure to use

```
'product_name like N''%абв%'''
```

into the line

```
select product_name from Products where '+@filters+'
```

**i.e.**

```
 select product_name from Products where product_name like N''%абв%'''
```

And **this WORKS**, so I don't know how to fix this..

Comment: First, I must point out that passing where clause as parameter and using it in dynamic SQL is really bad idea as it's vulnerable to SQL Injections. I don't know whatever that parameter is typed from some application, but imagine if someone sends you something like `@filters = '1=1)AS x)AS y; DROP TABLE Products; --'`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I know that this is vulnerable to SQL Injections, but I generate the filters myself, so there is no room for sql injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your problem with cyrillic inside parameters you just need to put another N in front of whole filter parameter when sending it

```
exec dbo.spGetProducts 'product_name','desc',0,50, N'product_name like N''%абв%'''
                                                   ^
                                                   ^
                                                  here
```

but please also read my comment about security issues and reconsider changing your design.

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9482/2)**

EDIT - a bit of explanation: If you do not specify that your input parameter is NVARCHAR it will be implicitly declared as VARCHAR, and your Cyrillic `абв` are lost and replaced with `???` before they even get to be passed to procedure.

If you are passing parameters from C# or VB, declaring them `DBType.NVarChar` should be enough to avoid the problem.

Comment: What will happen if we enter two like statements?
Does the N going to apply for both of them?

Comment: @Aleks If you mean two likes inside same `@filters` parameter - yes, N in front goes for whole parameter. Somthing like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8125e/1

Answer (score 0):

I am not surprised. You should be using parameters rather than concatenated SQL.

But it seems that your whole procedure needs to be re-written since you are using dynamic SQL.

Have a read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx), it'll help you out.